# Spark restart and optimize dump huge table job

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-standalone

I'm using Spark Standalone cluster manager. I'm dumping a huge tables with `runDumpJob` method (*see code below*). To launch a few `runDumpJob`s in parallel - I call `runDumpJob` from different threads.

### The problem

Some of `runDumpJob`s fail and aren't restarted by Spark automatically.

### Questions

1. *How could I restart failed job automatically?*
2. *How could I resume failed job automatically from some checkpoint?*

### Code

```
public void runDumpJob(SparkSession sparkSession, MyParams params) {

    final Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession
            .sqlContext()
            .read()
            .format("jdbc")
            .option("url", params.getJdbcUrl())
            .option("driver", params.getDriver())
            .option("dbtable", params.getSqlQuery())
            .option("fetchSize", params.getJobParam("fetchSize"))
            .load();
    dataset
        .coalesce(1)
        .write()
        .parquet(params.getPath());
}
```

Comment: You can save each partition separately to avoid memory overrun; if you coalesce into single partition and your input size is huge, your driver would run out of memory. if data is being saved in HDFS you can merge it using HDFS API or HDFS command, if it's saved elsewhere you can write a script/code to merge it.

Comment: @mbaxi isn't table dumped to the RAM of one specific worker? Let's assume you have 5 worker, each 16 Gb RAM, and one table 100GB. What you gonna do?

Comment: @mbaxi do you know how to make spark restart failed job automatically?

Comment: yup you are right it would be one specific worker that will get all the partitions and not the driver and would be limited by storage memory reserved for the worker, for restart part on yarn cluster it can be controlled at job level not sure how to do in standalone mode